# Считываю числа в Decimal вот так: b=Decimal(input()). Ошибка b=Decimal(input()) decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]

Tags: python, числа-с-плавающей-точкой, decimal

Пытаюсь подсчитать сумму максимальной возрастающей подпоследовательности из дробных чисел, взодные данные выглядят примерно так:

> 62.956673602019

> 7.707514622586

Использую вот такой код:

```
#в конец данных ввода всегда приписывать ноль
from decimal import *
sum=0
maxsum =0
a=Decimal(input())
b=Decimal(input())
i=0
sum=a
while i<499:
      if b>a:
            sum+=b
      else:
            if sum>maxsum:
                   maxsum=sum
            sum=b
      a=b
      b=Decimal(input())
      i+=1

if sum>maxsum:
      maxsum=sum


print(maxsum)
```

Пока числа с небольшим количеством знаков после запятой, всё, в принципе, работает, но как только знаков становится 10-15 появляется сообщение об ошибке:

> File "main.py", line 17, in 
> b=Decimal(input())
> decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]

Входные данные целиком:
101.220636490970
50.288165481106
60.578589406838
142.657509044419
82.255923900694
6.901291946238
118.900336325740
138.501142235941
89.286604150927
151.999939470340
31.367357252621
16.875550144525
121.008481481279
123.918231847840
76.125721031457
33.411236889951
127.460880097718
116.381504381886
129.299312661105
8.261892632856
99.290882628604
68.405301674300
60.475430399446
5.406143359740
138.978825504364
60.223977825444
20.247140902030
125.103785079248
12.797223308286
100.213387660448
89.345265357070
39.729141300045
14.372833734631
60.703399096488
153.830884179147
80.367744439851
35.587923364776
17.514374166533
68.749627230096
69.238328925956
40.039721057936
116.509161019140
24.158780734598
122.861656396602
20.575070084110
27.608680228880
62.753759704918
150.175000434034
118.224227016570
143.575207743212
77.068768086680
5.423501612052
82.230401548341
154.144696851226
36.616251379096
116.420225230739
118.947219827743
13.686269795024
152.579881987869
22.939894387968
44.614012802581
147.746406014113
19.150207791877
125.288675353400
113.106060037045
106.927375012088
36.241926048957
108.980164222628
58.974414271782
96.679599934299
85.377168055891
134.214970203779
45.556271030396
76.870692817981
19.085313620899
93.256470885460
149.285034022126
99.033476422879
127.722243391198
25.792227849364
60.528611636881
113.588132318204
30.250340290232
109.890629593084
133.290048297435
44.965897445456
45.253960319705
38.728611106011
31.123902574482
130.039118467561
152.177514563161
51.176578444498
96.574042413513
56.679022018086
134.857552891265
65.395378411004
147.788346015643
80.143068992499
103.133611232799
127.359061003739
42.606635349780
89.969914988795
100.938962756157
69.120317449264
93.565873814765
87.257247227152
68.731734105276
69.097608702469
104.405368183919
116.725126552486
114.241050269326
77.304189880452
20.385442777097
10.213117143667
28.835512933529
121.103112668434
43.258761299027
64.265631665493
134.017815722642
134.501761677624
146.443873543846
133.492563115220
54.436686519676
64.441237084959
141.337587063327
79.266676054023
123.866778113031
120.128190802503
66.984862916595
146.416480625431
18.794557995743
81.409830201311
40.421223371978
102.059933707653
59.228298410636
55.387508920014
151.079660807566
85.335916567461
23.168866199856
96.923632099496
112.447878281660
91.070112649954
81.844712471902
39.881086387743
57.089328853299
102.023173649970
105.820227598225
60.713846345477
139.684397103578
52.775033630111
150.441746000960
66.389822563272
121.881393898286
63.758798231887
109.750184273131
30.226847937408
90.969117359734
140.316935064078
137.246686494052
149.179046391943
106.919740153775
91.021711943242
70.416360472548
40.358852793728
136.937282614237
100.389220944702
84.480683946214
20.566935869985
72.525247284641
136.624002214004
75.730162323420
118.530558015002
124.851621501073
145.716682875210
47.663940815454
68.915371307236
146.890105660982
64.820114444975
133.018808825607
124.696169522164
28.316401977599
47.557692935049
101.433516833464
116.338453209673
58.789208141824
54.977017382723
110.864250196703
47.074691315119
98.053289776421
18.548997737802
132.834684028555
57.217530313406
54.489836151330
101.225210012956
17.010356356893
50.034058709329
40.395519116466
35.947150183435
115.002016682229
32.726744744091
94.212994719481
120.675990179288
52.820224480207
77.364488565707
48.651787179268
66.820302293646
79.454826071866
38.383976368953
58.610410366467
20.112502800314
117.935597854309
90.567996279699
89.147318593629
43.161308563501
10.543192595228
11.260318499886
85.898444931796
8.370988235685
68.141686366341
94.436192784053
63.288808290939
86.599596599297
111.106923770408
147.767823957036
126.686076900639
6.609600118180
109.720951666516
136.158498410960
40.899363369371
35.577130856231
9.130848328315
51.483170612700
87.384710295626
134.470799211142
113.415406323747
135.789118804892
71.930367598460
114.386183181096
55.130479295249
152.405614181909
133.676984133330
6.722298691538
70.226337895344
7.627093463974
112.855994070609
105.534237382930
131.154809946115
29.008954266764
128.312343441666
148.310398605063
21.187484033849
44.621038530267
12.721279603676
68.895969925557
26.673314002742
32.241357535371
17.642449464577
65.467905627308
107.993605720489
62.655474788352
92.436732771135
7.569552543019
110.004185795387
34.675606853693
97.095754325349
42.246443307994
135.103251007389
128.660323266170
48.596624871037
75.679283344075
92.207767880992
23.978054493476
44.095963090849
142.069594243639
106.107493877977
41.440593723079
109.682913145411
69.294140869092
14.270705050753
115.019381548792
45.295676246236
21.279977470842
132.781042050404
93.756257281543
85.512450630430
11.736306027145
50.561024597823
43.035757316747
151.226396263960
67.228911427232
103.116675463865
27.017925721391
146.262442412775
98.132055996630
125.683138237985
67.029546556932
14.681982184977
18.695232748836
24.408875829764
64.336455921575
11.475336178423
43.119403848837
100.938035061524
80.838875662512
83.088377706798
130.736226044434
136.615299972855
66.347608530801
18.273723502642
79.086406717916
52.789658031139
78.432291619425
60.092392983694
60.532058455466
11.598751600629
73.569544097166
112.681963510506
7.483361035440
16.191757775178
75.950913269012
51.870593262518
153.383999435160
54.763947129977
111.437504580578
148.364096387860
87.151084524880
150.389942642617
114.829833202337
64.275987513949
133.196426203369
152.027296370983
79.449392457912
145.028384261090
16.374717942714
84.480569208822
127.466685413422
89.978163391028
51.561245504056
17.089846691266
52.082421233434
86.270069362855
89.825118694945
47.490254878664
134.072961048416
55.153924608729
111.663241430578
90.401110125017
22.861232838166
84.830474614324
17.345238365716
61.999790779744
133.365753520094
25.705786093341
64.434922463994
101.772722334071
74.490919453387
79.303054322209
147.238655931277
21.322974922506
55.707850026810
18.628933238662
75.024347471083
148.751357558847
96.291400038303
139.527375617396
117.738244243186
21.450314977154
104.249815468182
51.080190121503
131.788699491239
21.062260177535
58.078278997256
11.005371780114
34.409971971693
13.332601904837
18.500909756591
79.362134736196
23.772701822103
7.926316481499
57.423222416247
84.674100402203
152.223842455912
29.384516289014
58.360251069824
65.908167386546
109.743117110811
61.471795236619
83.579102535457
105.213448472182
81.241002812525
6.171374564511
144.822483481585
127.005794749237
113.553275519039
73.215392355687
79.291193237624
135.943619309707
30.508573879260
147.548533167501
139.531639170519
55.614981626659
122.126439054459
78.712945200590
30.506223256007
16.722600625760
104.739103485487
65.407147555387
92.033667974694
121.047932945506
26.105380709174
100.174485246027
46.009155887618
53.717626661572
154.493777726348
10.555486416442
52.540935869345
80.101379210384
81.896626941872
113.263630255399
13.468158202605
11.226831594057
12.685454378632
138.990590581634
33.685435901962
77.760574062816
83.177864919278
131.321878578508
141.501383725998
149.826901733791
141.495995221309
148.861490430414
76.186676617138
37.621429436467
146.409141675243
83.264233428790
24.275949921801
11.724804706430
51.586693548712
126.259968718323
19.430085536476
32.341019191534
92.126685470415
11.916345234601
110.371551823166
39.315927266647
36.257465320230
92.172099285139
31.645565564932
90.645564969921
45.463710964197
122.985884936444
50.494668871302
17.403411848618
66.500248939457
82.580763917608
20.160979214331
75.622620934434
154.696401521987
136.513596197619
76.928331958843
127.034199140291
69.091480304005
124.044892461979
23.495812016210
151.552606431901
37.158378832041
5.744473623208
141.768617056716
8.975582274280
123.326025248515
44.753835352172
8.853742102299
112.660617985013
142.077480732129
111.264176489746
11.530462180930
44.913560982983
67.217035189953
40.879637721153
70.242566183866
69.658371520613
50.990559422080
85.647132363150
29.403773086793
111.444590954250
140.470240991661
120.413054296444
125.449844881779
34.219542260756
68.473238115089
11.767371558815
88.362232143135
62.956673602019
7.707514622586
46.840277145853
61.855458050986
90.923870916500
74.220581092679
74.977363508624
59.988071183857

[image: Делаю в реплите, не работает]

Comment: А после какого числа происходит ошибка?

Comment: Ну странно, я попробовал очень много цифр печатать и до точки и после и никаких ошибок. Там какой-то неправильный символ явно закрался. Знаков по 100 сейчас напечатал и до точки и после - и всё ок.

Comment: В общем, покажите конкретный ввод, на котором ломается. Может там запятая вместо точки или ещё какой неправильный символ.

Comment: Я попробовал оооооочень длинное число - вот такое `Decimal('5555.' + '8'*999999)`. И нормально воспринялось. Явно у вас на входе были какие-то лишние символы.

Comment: Все ваши данные прекрасно сконвертировались в Decimal. Если убрать восклицательный знак в начале строки.

Comment: Убрала (я пыталась сделать "спойлер", ну, чтобы можно было убрать все эти числа и менее муторно было листать вниз, поэтому его поставила)

Comment: Какой ответ должен быть?

Comment: Во входных данных 500 чисел. А программа ожидает ввода 501, хотя последнее нигде не используется.

Comment: Знаю про последнее число, вверху в коде комментарий про него. Это задание из ЕГЭ, думала, напишу абы как, лишь бы работало, и отделаюсь. Но тут всплыла эта ошибка, которая выскакивает ещё до ввода последнего числа

Comment: Судя по скриншоту, все 500 чисел зачитались. А 501 "отсутствующее" и, видимо, вызывает ошибку.

Comment: А, всё, поняла, спасибо) Сработало) Как думаете, вопрос удалить или пусть остаётся?

Comment: Вообще, в обычном Python выскакивает ошибка "конец файла". Так что исправьте код, чтобы читало только 500 чисел. Просто уберите первый`b=Decimal(input())`, а второй переставьте в начало цикла.